# How to point two different domains to one site in WP Multisite Network?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite installation. In my multisite network each of my sites has its own domain pointing to it; they all work fine.

But now I need to point two different domains to one of these sites.

The problem is that in cpanel all parked domains point to the root folder, and then in Wordpress I use Site Address (URL) in Site Info to tell Wordpress which of the sites in network uses which domain. And there is only one Site Address for each site... so how do I add second domain to a specific site in the network?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need something like [Mercator](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator) or WP Ultimo or WPMuDev's Domain Mapping.

Mercator is my recommendation and even what is used by most WP Ultimo installations.